# WPF: Event Handlers in Codebehind's Constructor not hooking up

Tags: wpf, constructor, event-handling

Sit Rep
I have a WPF app. In the constructor of the (C#) code-behind I attach a button event-handler. Problem is, it doesn't attach! But if I attach it via clicking a UI button, then the button works fine. Also, of course, if I attach it in the button's XAML it works too.

So, it appears that the prob is attaching the handler in the constructor. It seems to be too early in the process.

[App Image](http://screencast.com/t/ZTU4NDM3)

This is what I want, but doesn't attach:

```
public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();

   //...
   //
   //  TEST RADIO BUTTONS
   //
   //  THIS HANDLER DOESN'T ATTACH!
   ui_Test.Click += (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) =>
   {
       bool localOnly = Convert.ToBoolean(ui_rdoLocal.IsChecked);
       bool onlineOnly = Convert.ToBoolean(ui_rdoOnline.IsChecked);
       bool both = Convert.ToBoolean(ui_rdoBoth.IsChecked);

       string message = "Local: {1}{0}Online: {2}{0}Both: {3}".Put(nl, localOnly, onlineOnly, both);
       MessageBox.Show(message);
    };

   //...
}
```

And here's the code for a second test button which attaches the above code via a button click. This handler is set in XAML. The handler then works, but I want to attach the handler in C#, not XAML.

```
<Button Name="ui_Test2" Content="Attach Annonymous Handlers" Margin="30,10" Click="ui_Test2_Click"></Button>
```

And the method:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Attaches control handlers. Will they attach now? YES!!
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void ui_Test2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ui_Test.Click += (object sndr, RoutedEventArgs rea) =>
            {
                bool localOnly = Convert.ToBoolean(ui_rdoLocal.IsChecked);
                bool onlineOnly = Convert.ToBoolean(ui_rdoOnline.IsChecked);
                bool both = Convert.ToBoolean(ui_rdoBoth.IsChecked);

                string message = "Local: {1}{0}Online: {2}{0}Both: {3}".Put(nl, localOnly, onlineOnly, both);
                MessageBox.Show(message);
            };
    }
```

Thx in advance for any help!

Gregg

Comment: Your code looks fine, and it's not too early in the process (since you're after InitializeComponent).  I just did a test and (a simplified version of) your code is working for me.  Have you tried a simplified repro?  If you put a breakpoint on the Click assignment, is it ever hit?  (E.g. could there be an exception earlier in the constructor which is causing it to be skipped?)

Comment: You were right on - there was an exception being thrown prior to the handler being attached. Write your reply as an answer and I'll give it the Big Tick.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to attach handler after calling InitializeComponent(); in constructor.

Comment: Thanks. Actually it is after that call. I'll add it above to clarify for others though.